# Error converting .ui file (made with PyQT4) to python file

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I downloaded PyQT4 from here http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

I downloaded file named PyQt4-4.11.1-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.6-x64.exe (first one under binary packages), then I downloaded python 3.4.1 from here https://www.python.org/download/ (an x64 version just like pyqt).

After that, I started up qt designer (found in my PyQT4 folder), made some simple GUI and when I got to the part of converting the .ui file to .py file I get an error that goes like this:

```
'"E:\PyQT4\python"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

My PyQT is installed in `E:\PyQT4`, and my python in `E:\Python3.4.1`.

I started up cmd prompt, did that `cd E:\....` thing, went to my folder where my simple GUI is saved and wrote this line in cmd:

```
 pyuic4 -o TestniGUI_ui.py TestniGUI.ui
```

and got that error I was talking about earlier.

Is anybody familiar with anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide full path to pyuic4

```
E:\Python3.4.1\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4 %path_for_ui_file\your_file.ui -o %path_for_py_file\your_file.py
```

Or you can do

```
cd E:\Python3.4.1\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
pyuic4 %path_for_ui_file\your_file.ui -o %path_for_py_file\your_file.py
```

Comment: I managed to solve it by installing both PyQT and Python in the default location :)

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you have to add to the `PATH` environment variable the folders containing Python's executable/interpeter and binaries you use from qt (pyuic4, pyrcc4, ...). In your case you have to add:

> E:\Python3.4.1 and E:\PyQT4

to your path.

[Here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) you have a little tuto on how to set a environment variables.